What advantage is there in using hardware PWM with pigpio?
Normally I just use the set_servo_pulsewidth() method (which is "hardware timed").
I understand that this pulse width is managed in software, and that to use hardware PWM, I need to use hardware_PWM() instead (on the two GPIO channels that support it).
What advantage is there in using hardware PWM - under what circumstances would a difference be apparent?
(I am using 9g hobby servo motors, and although they are very far from being precision devices it's definitely possible to get less precision and control with certain methods of driving them, especially with a Pi that's having to do a lot of things at once.)


What advantage is there in using hardware PWM

Hardware PWM means there is a physical clock dedicated to emitting pulses.  This is extremely accurate.  Hardware clocks are fundamental to microcontrollers and microprocessors.  Their timing is implemented using crystal oscillators, ie., they are tighly bound to some basic laws of physics that are not significantly subject to variable infuences.
There may only be one such oscillator in an MC/MP (I believe this is the case with all Pi models), but the signal from it can be put to multiple simultaneous purposes (much like how one bulb can illuminate everything in a room) and sub-divided to produce pulses of (a lower) specific frequency.  This is what hardware clocks are; each can produce one frequency at a time and while they can be controlled with software, you cannot use software to create more of them.
Software PWM is only clock dependent to the extent that the whole processor and operating system is.  The OS is essentially a loop that exploits the processor timing and serves/controls individual applications and programs.  Their activity is timed sliced through processor cores, which are limited in number and clock controlled, but since the time slicing is controlled by the OS, which is subject to variable influences and concerns, this is a little more indeterminate.
In a nutshell: Software PWM runs as a userspace application on a processor core and may be intermittently interrupted by other applications or operating system activity, which can cause jitter.  Hardware PWM comes directly from a dedicated, uninterruptible clock signal and so is not subject to such jitter but may be subject to minor fluctuations in voltage because of system load and how much current is drawn from whatever they control.1
On a multi-core system with very little load, software PWM can be very accurate/jitterless, but this is still without the law of physics type guarantee that applies to hardware PWM.

The clock signal on a GPIO controls the GPIO via a transistor and -- I'm not an electrical engineer and this is a bit off the cuff conjecture -- if the load on the transistor varies enough it may cause some latency or warping of the signal.  So some hardware PWM pipelines may be better than others depending on the quality of their components.


While it is true that the Pi has only a single crystal oscillator it has multiple hardware clocks, phase locked to the master and these are rock solid. Some of these clocks can vary (in the  ratio and thus frequency) once the divider/multiplier is set they are as stable as the master.

I don't think that contradicts anything I wrote, seems like a re-phrasing of the second paragraph...

pigpioddoesn't have hardware PWM, but has hardware timed PWM which works on any GPIO. It provides a limited range of frequencies.
This is suitable for servos whereas software PWM (provided by other libraries) causes jitter (and possible damage to servo).
pigpiod has explicit support for servos

https://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#hardware_PWM says that the hardware_PWM() method "Starts hardware PWM on a GPIO at the specified frequency and dutycycle". I'd understand "hardware PWM" to mean that it's fully-managed in hardware.

I must be mistaken, I was going from memory and have used hardware timed PWM; I was sure it wasn't there. I actually use my own library, or more recently the kernel PWM.
